# How can I move a container closer to the overlaying logo using Flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, padding

I want to move the container with all the login info, closer to the overlaying logo.

How can I do that?

I am using flutter.dart.

Here is my code: https://github.com/wileecoyote2point0/math_game

I have tried adjusting padding

No luck

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this i was you want to do right? it not please let me know.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'package:math_game/signup.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.purple),
        home: new LoginPage(),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/signup': (BuildContext context) => new SignupPage()
        });
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new LoginPageState();
}

class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> _iconAnimation;
  AnimationController _iconAnimationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _iconAnimationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
    _iconAnimation = new CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _iconAnimationController, curve: Curves.easeOut);
    _iconAnimation.addListener(() => this.setState(() {}));
    _iconAnimationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent,
      body: new Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Image(
            image: new AssetImage("assets/nevroner3.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            color: Colors.black87,
            colorBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
          ),
          new Theme(
            data: new ThemeData(
              brightness: Brightness.dark,
              inputDecorationTheme: new InputDecorationTheme(
                labelStyle:
                    new TextStyle(color: Colors.tealAccent, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            isMaterialAppTheme: true,
            child: new Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
              child: new Form(
                autovalidate: true,
                child: new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Image(
                      image: new AssetImage("assets/math_logo3.png"),
                    ),
                    new TextFormField(
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Enter Email",
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    ),
                    new TextFormField(
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Enter Password",
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      obscureText: true,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    ),
                    new Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    ),
                    new MaterialButton(
                        color: Colors.teal,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        child: new Text("Login"),
                        onPressed: () => {}),
                    new SizedBox(width: 20.0, height: 5.0),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "New to Math Messenger ?",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    new SizedBox(width: 5.0, height: 10.0),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Register",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.tealAccent,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your login info container is wrapped inside `expanded widget` which will take all the available space after your logo, thus logo gets pushed at top of screen 

Remove the expanded widget and add following to your column containing logo and login container,

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
```

remove crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,

Answer (score 0):

Used MainAxisSize.min instead of MainAxisAlignment.center 
on both the container and logo.
Adjusted padding and it worked perfectly.

[image]